# How does Yii link the attributes array of CActiveRecord to the class members?

Tags: php, yii

I have never seen this before and would like to understand it. Here is the code I ran:

```
$q = new CDbCriteria(array(
    'condition'=>'"pKey" = :pKey',
    'params' => array(':pKey'=>$id)
));     
$oldmodel = Inventory::model()->find($q); //Inventory extends CActiveRecord
$oldmodel->equipmentType = 'Display';
$tmp = $oldmodel->equipmentType;
$tmp2 = $oldmodel->attributes['equipmentType'];
```

The outcome is that as soon as I change `$oldmodel->equipmentType`, `$oldmodel->attributes['equipmentType']` will follow suit; `$tmp` and `$tmp2` will be set to 'Display' afterwards.

How is it that a class member can be linked to an array like this? This doesn't work for all of the public members of the class (I expected this). I just want to know how I can do this myself because it seems really interesting!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`equipmentType` is not a public attribute.

When you `find` (or `findAll`) a [`CActiveRecord`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord), [populateRecord()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#populateRecord-detail) is called, which has the following code (`$attributes` are the column=>value pairs from the database. Note specifically the `foreach` loop.):

```
public function populateRecord($attributes,$callAfterFind=true)
{
    if($attributes!==false)
    {
        $record=$this->instantiate($attributes);
        $record->setScenario('update');
        $record->init();
        $md=$record->getMetaData();
        foreach($attributes as $name=>$value)
        {
            if(property_exists($record,$name))
                $record->$name=$value;
            elseif(isset($md->columns[$name]))
                $record->_attributes[$name]=$value;
        }
        $record->_pk=$record->getPrimaryKey();
        $record->attachBehaviors($record->behaviors());
        if($callAfterFind)
            $record->afterFind();
        return $record;
    }
    else
        return null;
}
```

So, in your case, `$Inventory->_attribute['equipmentType']` is populated with the data from the database.

If you then try to reference the psuedo property `equipmentType`, you actually end up calling the magic [__get()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#__get-detail) method on the CActiveRecord instance.

As you can see, the first `if` statement will be true, causing the stored value to be returned.

```
public function __get($name)
{
    if(isset($this->_attributes[$name]))
        return $this->_attributes[$name];
    elseif(isset($this->getMetaData()->columns[$name]))
        return null;
    elseif(isset($this->_related[$name]))
        return $this->_related[$name];
    elseif(isset($this->getMetaData()->relations[$name]))
        return $this->getRelated($name);
    else
        return parent::__get($name);
}
```

Note that [__set()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#__set-detail) will work in a complementary way, so that when you set the attribute yourself (other than just when it loads from the database), then it updates the `_attributes` property as well.

Finally, when you try to access the `attributes` property as an array, as you do with `$oldmodel->attributes['equipmentType'];`, you are actually calling the [getAttributes()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#getAttributes-detail) method, which again, will return the attribute as stored in the `_attributes` property.

So, long story short, heavy use (or abuse) of the magic __get and __set methods allows this to occur. Note, I believe (but haven't traced the logic fully myself) that in order to access the `attributes` using array syntax, you must, like CActiveRecord, implement [ArrayAccess](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php) on your class.

Just follow the documentation page instructions, and see how CActiveRecord implements the required methods, and you should be able to repeat the result.

Comment: Very well explained! Thanks for the time. I didn't know about __get() or __set(). It's great to learn something new!

Comment: A word of advice: All these magic properties are useful, but at the same time they violate the principle of least astonishment. If you make use of them, use them with care, and with a specific goal in mind, because they will significantly increase the learning curve of anyone else who looks at your code, including yourself in 3, 6, or whenever months from now.